# spill error while trying to execute excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

single word is present in the A column which has 1132 rows whereas in E column a description is present.
Now the Scenario is, i need to search for all the keywords in A row whether it is present in E column cell or not. i used the below formula it is throwing SPILL error. Can someone please guide in this.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$1132,E2)),"Valid","")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in OR()

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$1132,E2))),"Valid","")
```